# Get the index of child to it's parent in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

This is my html code.

```
<ul class="listClass">
    <li>List1</li>
    <li>List2</li>
    <li>List3</li>
    <li>List4</li>
    <li>List5</li>
</ul>
```

I'm adding an onClick eventListener to the child `<li>`s, which should output me the correct index of that child `<li>`

Here's the javascript

```
var lists = document.querySelectorAll('.listClass li');
for (var i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
    lists[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        console.log(e);
      console.log('My index:', i);
    }, false);
}
```

It always outputs:My index: 5

While I clearly understand that, it's taking the reference of `i`, Is there any other way I can store the correct value of `i`.

Two possible approaches that I found out.

1st: Jquery's `index()` method. https://api.jquery.com/index/

2nd: DOM event delegation. [What is DOM Event delegation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation)

Is there any other approach that can be used?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a property to your element

```js
var list2 = document.querySelectorAll('.list2 li');

for (var i = 0; i < list2.length; i++) {  
  
  list2[i].index = i;
  
  list2[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    
    alert('My index:' + e.target.index);
    
  });
  
}
```

```html
<ul class="list2">
    <li>Text</li>
    <li>Text</li>
    <li>Text</li>
    <li>Text</li>
    <li>Text</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: WOW, Seriously!.
Thanks for the response.